# Caching Web Client in Vert.x

Tags: vert.x, vertx-httpclient

This is the architecture I am trying to build where I first check in Redis cache and incase of a cache miss go to downstream. Found Caching web client in vert x 4.2.0 and newer version but does that allow us to communicate with Redis cache or it works with in-memory cache only ? Also any suggestions to achieve this are welcome.

[Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQXe6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently vert.x web client doesn't have any redis based caching implementation, yet nothing really stops one from quickly building one.

The important bit is the interface `io.vertx.ext.web.client.spi.CacheStore`. A custom implementation that stores data in redis would sufice to get your architecture complete.

Currently, vert.x web client offers a local in-memory cache or a `SharedData` based cache, usefull for sharing data across verticles.

If one would follow the shared data implementation as a blueprint, supporting redis would be a nice good first contribution project.